# Is the AR(1) process always Gaussian given Gaussian innovations?

Tags: r, time-series, gaussian-process, arma

I found that $AR(1)$ process $x_t=\phi x_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$ is not always Gaussian given Gaussian innovations $\epsilon_t$. This only happens when the $AR(1)$ model coefficient is very large. This goes against with [the theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) (If the white noise $\epsilon_t$ is a Gaussian process then $x_t$ is also a Gaussian process). How to explain this then? The following R codes gives that only $363$ out of the 1000 generations of $AR(1$) processes are gaussian process by the  `Shapiro-Wilk  test`.

```
decision=c()
for (k in 1:1000){ # 1000 runs 
  phi=0.9 # AR(1) coefficient
  x=0.5 # value of x_0
  X=c() # generated AR(1) process
  for (i in 1:1000){  # length of the process is 1000
    x=phi*x+rnorm(1) # Gaussian innovations
    X=c(X,x) 
  }  
  decision=c(decision,shapiro.test(X)$p.value) # Gaussian test
}
sum(decision>0.05)/1000 # percentage of Gaussian processes
```

Comment: How did you determine that it is "not Gaussian"?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I performed the Shapiro test to test for normal.

Comment: (1) the name of the test you applied is the [*Shapiro-Wilk* test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test). (2) It requires that the observations be *independent*. You don't have that (by design), so you can't conclude anything about normality from its high rejection rate.

Comment: Well,since i am not familiar with the R code, I take it that the software automatically understands that "phi*x" means "phi*x(t-1)". Since it is pretty easy to deduce that

Comment: Actually, scratch that, it looks right as far as generating an AR, but it's a rather odd way to do it. I bet it runs very slowly because the code is growing a vector inside nested loops. OP, the way you generate that, your $x$'s aren't identically distributed as well as being dependent.

Comment: @GLEN_b (CONT'D) ...deduce that $x_t = x_0 +\sum_{j=1}^t\phi^{j-1}\varepsilon _{t+1-j}$, there is no way that they are not Gaussian. Paper and pen prevail over software code in such cases.

Comment: @Glen_b The expression was not meant for you Glen_b, but to take out any possible thought from the mind of the OP that (s)he just might have hit on an exception of the theory that is not usually mentioned, and so that the OP has only to look towards either the code or the test used.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. Do you mean the Shapiro-Wilk test is not applicable for the process here because the process is not independent? BTW, I am confused because the high rejection rate only happens when $\phi$ is as large as $0.9$. E.g., everything goes well for $\phi=0.8$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the Shapiro Wilk, as stated at the link I gave, assumes independence. Because of the way it works, it is fairly robust to mild dependence, however. Note that up at $\phi=0.9$ you're getting toward the region of nonstationarity and there you don't have unconditional normality. One piece of advice: run your simulation of the AR(1) for quite a few steps before recording the values for your sample, or it won't be sufficiently close to stationary. You might want to investigate the use of `filter` or `rollapply` (in package `zoo`) to generate your AR, or even easier `arima.sim`.

Comment: @Glen_b So the theory "If the white noise $\epsilon_t$ is a Gaussian process then $x_t$ is also a Gaussian process" is right. I got strange results just because the use of Gaussian test is not proper here.

Comment: To clarify further (I hope); by 'toward the region of nonstationarity' I mean that when you get close to $\phi=1$ that even though your process is stationary, the sample behaviour in samples can sometimes mimic a nonstationary process for a fair while (and increasingly so as you get closer); you need bigger and bigger samples to see it. Similarly, effects of initial values propagate further and further; with larger $\phi$ it takes a longer warmup before your series behaves like a stationary AR.

Comment: @Glen_b Good point. Then do you have any suggestion about a quantitative way to show whether a AR(1) process is Gaussian?

Comment: You can simply use something like this to generate your AR(1): ts.sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.9), n = 1000)

Comment: @Stat I was testing whether $x_t$ is Gaussian given different innovations (not only Gaussian). The `arima.sim` uses gaussian innovations by default.

Comment: You can't show an observed process *is* Gaussian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By way of summary of the comments, so that this question has an answer (if Alecos would like to present a summary I'll happily delete this and upvote it instead, as long as the question ends up with an answer) --

As Alecos points out, the AR(1) process for $\phi=0.9$ is definitely Gaussian.

Since it's stationary, observations from it should all have the same Gaussian distribution; the OP is right to expect that it should, since it's undeniably so. As Alecos says, the pen-and-paper result should suggest there's a problem with either the code or the test.

There are in fact several such problems:

(1) The Shapiro Wilk test assumes independence. We don't have it so the test doesn't apply. The OP notes that the test doesn't seem to have problems even with moderately large values of the parameter, and that's not surprising - because of the way the test works, it should be fairly robust to mild dependence. The Shapiro-Wilk doesn't look at the dependence in consecutive values. The most noticeable effect of the dependence on the distribution of the order statistics will be to increase their variance, but the Shapiro Wilk won't notice that at all. There will be a tendency for the tails to wander more from the straight line than with an independent series and eventually that sort of deviation will become detectable.

(2) The code doesn't have any warmup period. The mean and variance of the early values won't correspond to the mean and variance of the AR(1) process (so we don't have independence OR identically distributed values).