# Why, empirically, does strict stationarity only hold *asymptotically* for an AR(1) process?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

A Gaussian AR(1) process with autocorrelation $|\phi|<1$ is strictly stationary, [meaning that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Definition):

$$F_{X}(x_{t_1+\tau} ,\ldots, x_{t_n+\tau}) = F_{X}(x_{t_1},\ldots, x_{t_n}) \quad \text{for all } \tau,t_1, \ldots, t_n \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$$

As we can see from the "for all $\tau \in \mathcal{R}$", strict stationarity by definition must hold even in *finite* samples.

However, as a [previous question demonstrated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69419/is-the-ar1-process-always-gaussian-given-gaussian-innovations), simulated Gaussian AR(1) processes clearly don't achieve stationarity, even weak stationarity, until after some number of draws has elapsed. (My own MWE appears below.) In the comment thread, `Glen_b` helpfully explains:

> ...when you get close to =1...even though your process is stationary, the sample behaviour in samples can sometimes mimic a nonstationary process for a fair while (and increasingly so as you get closer); you need bigger and bigger samples to see it. Similarly, effects of initial values propagate further and further; with larger  it takes a longer warmup before your series behaves like a stationary AR.

**Given that the above definition of strict stationarity is clearly a finite-sample rather than an asymptotic property, why does stationarity only seem to hold asymptotically in simulation?**

#### MWE showing finite-sample non-stationarity

Here's a quick example showing that the SD of the draws in increasing in $t$ until approximately the 20$^{th}$ draw. Here, I simulate 1,000 individual time series from the same underlying AR(1) process with $\phi=0.9$ and errors $\epsilon_{t} \sim N(0, 0.5)$. The plot shows the standard deviation across the 1,000 time series of random variable $X_t$, conditional on $t$ (labeled `draw.index`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(simts)

# number of time series to simulate
k = 1000

# number of draws in each series
draws = 100

# simulate Gaussian AR(1)'s with autocorrelation = 0.9
for ( i in 1:k ) {
  .d = data.frame( yi = as.numeric( gen_gts( draws, AR1(phi = 0.9, sigma2 = 0.5) ) ) )
  .d$iterate = i
  .d$draw.index = 1:nrow(.d)
  if ( i == 1 ) d = .d else d = bind_rows(d, .d)
}

agg = d %>% group_by(draw.index) %>%
  summarise( Mean = mean(yi),
             SD = sd(yi) )

plot(agg$draw.index, agg$SD, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: It is helpful to distinguish among (1) a time series process, (2) a time series, and (3) finite-length samples of either.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126830/919 for some discussion and a reference.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. These distinctions make sense, but given that what I'm plotting is an average over 1,000 realizations (i.e., time series) of this stochastic process, not a single realization, I'm not seeing how this resolves the question.

Comment: Because reading your code requires familiarity with `R` along with extra packages, It is difficult to determine exactly what you *are* plotting: a verbal description would be helpful.

Comment: Right, thanks. I've edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> strict stationarity by definition must hold even in finite samples

It must hold for a finite number of *random variables* $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_t\}$ that are part of the stochastic process. $F_X(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_t)$ is the joint CDF of all these $t$ *random variables*, and the $x_t$s are the possible values a particular random variable $X_t$ can take. So, the definition of stationarity is not about samples $x_t$, but about random variables $X_t$.

However, you don't know the CDF of any $X_t$ in *one* simulation since one realization of a stochastic process contains *one* sample $x_t$ per each random variable $X_t$. Thus, in order to say anything about the process, you'll need multiple realizations of it.

If your process is [ergodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process), you can learn more about it by observing more and more individual realizations $x_t$ from this *one* ongoing process, so you don't need multiple full realizations of the process. That's why you can "see" stationarity on the plot.

Comment: But this simulation *does* have multiple realizations (i.e., 1000) of $\{ X_1, \cdots, X_{100} \}$.

Comment: @half-pass, it has one realization of $X_1$, one realization of $X_2$, one realization of $X_3$ and so on. If you sample the process once more, you'll get the second realization of $X_1$, the second realization of $X_2$ and so on. Each $x_t$ in your sample $\{X_1, X_2, \dots\}$ comes from its own random variable $\{X_1, X_2, \dots\}$. Ah, okay, i get it. This code indeed samples the process multiple times